# IE8 :focus causes issue - need to double click

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, focus

I'm using :focus on a select dropdown. In IE8 this requires two clicks, one activates the focus (I can see by the styling I have) the next actually gives the drop down. When I remove the focus style all works as expected in IE8.

Anyone come across this issue?  I have a Doc type set, so it's not that issue.

```
input[type='text'], select, textarea {
   border:1px solid clack;
   box-shadow: 0;
   padding:8px;
   font-size:14px;
   padding:8px;
   background:white; 
}

select:focus {
        border:2px solid yellow;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow:none;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix your problem (IE 8.0 fix)

```
<style>
    select { background-color: #BDE5F8; }
    select:focus, select.focus { 
background-color: white; 
    /*Style here*/
}
</style>

<!--[if lt IE 8]><script>
    // Javascript only
    var selects= document.getElementsByTagName('select');
    for (var i= selects.length; i-- >0;) {
        var select= selects[i];
        select.onfocusin= function() {
            this.className= 'focus';
        };
        select.onfocusout= function() {
            this.className= '';
        };
    }

    // Jquery fix
    $('select').bind('focusin', function() {
        $(this).addClass('focus');
    }).bind('focusout', function() {
        $(this).removeClass('focus');
    });
</script><![endif]-->
```